# Word for a short promotional video

Tags: single-word-requests

I know that usually a short video with audio is called "clip", but at least for me, it's associated with a music video, MTV, etc, and doesn't sound professional enough.

So is there a single word for a short video promoting a company, showing the company skills and past achievements etc?

It is going to be used in a presentation which is going to start with the video, and contains Table of Contents as the first slide. So far we have "[company name] Video Clip" but like I said in the beginning, it doesn't feel right. Neither me nor the audience of the presentation are native English speakers, if it matters.

Answer (score 7):

The word [***promo***](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=promo&t=crmtb01) is often used.

Simply an abbreviation of promotional video, it is widely used to describe the type of short video that you mention.  A video concentrating on the company itself rather than an advertisement which concentrates on its products.

Comment: That sounds more like it, thanks! Didn't think of this.

Answer (score 3):

Surely this is a good one :-)

> A **showreel** (also known as a **demo reel**) is a short piece of
>   video or film footage showcasing an actor's previous work. Usually
>   four to six minutes in length, a showreel typically supplements an
>   actor's résumé and is used to promote the artist's skill, talent, and
>   experience to acting agents and casting directors.
>
> [From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Showreel_%28actors%29)

Answer (score 1):

I think a good general term for this sort of thing would be *portfolio*. In practice I've seen this term used when I've reviewed potential companies to award design and programming contracts to, for instance. The dictionary says:

> portfolio: a set of pieces of creative work collected by someone to display their skills, esp. to a potential employer

From show-business come the related terms *showreel*  and *demo reel* (sometimes heard as *reel*, as in "I'd love you to take a look at my reel"). Dictionary says:

> showreel: a short videotape containing examples of an actor's or director's work for showing to potential employers

And of course the related terms *résumé* and *curriculum vitae* tend to cover the case of a written document which is used when seeking individual employment.

All of the above terms yield good google results, including forum discussions regarding specific uses of the terms in particular industries.

Answer (score 0):

*[Presentation](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/presentation) video*  is the expression generally used:

> - (Commerce) a verbal report presented with illustrative material, such as slides, graphs, etc: a presentation on the company results.

(TFD)

Comment: But presentation is the overall presentation, the video is only a small part of it. Or am I missing something?

Comment: That specific video is the *presentation video* which will be used during the presentation of the  company , its history, its economic trends etc.!!

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean, sorry. My question is about a short video which is just part of a presentation, not the presentation itself.